# How to include dot once as last character in regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to make regex in JavaScript that matches numbers between 1-100 and includes two decimals.
Example numbers that need to be included in the regex:

`1`
`1.1`
`1.15`
`0.5`
`100`
`100.00`

Example numbers that need to be excluded:

`101`
`100.01`
`100.1`
`55.999`

This is my regex at the moment:

```
^(?:100(?:\.00?)?|\d?\d(?:\.\d\d?)?)$
```

This works otherwise but I also need to include two numbers followed by a decimal or 100 followed by a decimal like this:

`14.`
`9.`
`100.`

This is because I'm running the regex check each time a button is pressed in an input field and even though number like 0.5 is allowed by the current regex, I can't type it in because 0. is not allowed.

Comment: Is `.5` a valid match?

Comment: As often repeated, the [Stack Overflow `regex` tag info page](/tags/regex/info) contains some guidelines which your question needs to meet. In particular, please [edit] to indicate which programming language, regex tool, or platform you are targeting.

Comment: @anubhava 0.5 is but .5 is not valid. Well I guess it doesn't hurt if .5 is accepted as well

Comment: @tripleee I edited the question to include JavaScript as the language, thanks

Comment: @user1589375: ok in my answer I have allowed `0.5` and `.5` as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use two separate regexps here, one for the live input validation (just what you described in the question, that will let you input allowed values), and another one for a final "on-submit" validation (that will check the validity of the whole input string).
Otherwise, you won't be able to input `0.5` like values.

The regex for live input validation is:

```js
/^(?:100(?:\.0?0?)?|\d\d?(?:\.\d?\d?)?)$/
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eT4G9s/1). Note how the `?` quantifiers make patterns optional, especially the `\d` and `0` after `\.`  patterns.

The regex for final validation of numbers starting with `0.01` to `100` is

```js
/^(?!0*(?:\.0*)?$)(?:100(?:\.00?)?|\d?\d?(?:\.\d\d?)?)$/
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eT4G9s/2).

Answer (score 1):

Make the numbers after the dot optional, too.

```
^(?:100(?:\.00?)?|\d?\d(?:\.\d{0,2})?)$
```

If you want to disallow 0 before the dot if the numbers after are all zero or nothing, probably include a separate negative lookahead for that:

```
^(?:100(?:\.00?)?|(?!0\.0*$)\d?\d(?:\.\d{0,2})?)$
```

Nothing here or in your original regex should disallow `0.5`; perhaps add more debugging details if that is genuinely something you are grappling with.

Answer (score 1):

You may use this regex for your task:

```sh
^(?:0?\.(?:\d?[1-9]|[1-9]\d)|[1-9]\d?(?:\.\d{1,2})?|100(?:\.0{1,2})?)$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Yuafjq/3)

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples, could you please try following.

```
^(?:100(?:\.0{1,2})?|(?:(?:\d\d?)(?:\.\d{1,2})?))$
```

[Online demo for above regex](https://regex101.com/r/MpYKnA/1)

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
^                      ##Matching from starting of value here.
(?:                    ##Starting 1st capturing group here.
  100(?:\.0{1,2})?|    ##matching 100 with or without 1 to 2 zeroes OR
  (?:                  ##Starting 2nd capturing group here.
     (?:\d\d?)         ##In a non-capturing group matching 0 to 9 and 0 to 9 optional.
     (?:\.\d{1,2})?    ##In a non-capturing group matching dot followed by 1 or 2 digits
  )                    ##Closing 2nd capturing group here.
)$                     ##Closing 1st capturing group at the end of value.
```